# python check for alternating monday starting on certain date

Tags: python

```
my_date = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Central'))
```

So, I have a date `my_date` and I want to check if this datetime object is an alternating Tuesday starting on the week of September 2nd.  So if `my_date` is the 4th, it should return true, 11th false, 18th true, etc.. How would this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, which compute first tuesday of a given month, and use datetime.isocalendar to fetch week number and check "alternate"

```py
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta


def first_tuesday_of_month(year, month):
    first_day_of_month = datetime(year, month, 1)
    days_diff = ((1 - first_day_of_month.weekday()) + 7) % 7
    first_tuesday_of_month = first_day_of_month + timedelta(days=days_diff)
    return first_tuesday_of_month


def is_alternate_tuesday(starting_day, date_to_check):
    # First check if the date is a Tuesday after the starting_day
    if date_to_check < starting_day or date_to_check.weekday() != 1:
        return False

    # Ok, let's check if it's an "alternate week"
    base_week = starting_day.isocalendar()[1]
    checked_week = week_to_check = date_to_check.isocalendar()[1]
    return (checked_week - base_week) % 2 == 0


base_day = first_tuesday_of_month(2018, 9)

assert is_alternate_tuesday(base_day , datetime(2018, 9, 4)) is True
assert is_alternate_tuesday(starting_day, datetime(2018, 9, 11)) is False
assert is_alternate_tuesday(starting_day, datetime(2018, 9, 18)) is True
```

Comment: `assert is_alternate_tuesday(base_day , datetime(2018, 9, 6)) is True` This is returning true.  However, it should be false, as 2018/9/6 is a wednesday.

Comment: Right, I modify my code. But @Acccumulation answer is far more simple (I should remove my answer).

Answer (score 1):

One method is

```
(test_date-datetime.date(2018, 9, 4)).days %14 ==0
```

If it's within the same year, you can also use

```
(test_date.isocalendar()[1]- datetime.date(2018, 9, 4).isocalendar()[1] %2) == 0 and test_date.isocalendar()[2]==2
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for this problem should be like.

```
if datetime.date.today() in [datetime.date(2020, 6, 1) + timedelta(x) for x in range(14, 365, 14)]:
    print "This day is alternate Monday"
else:
    print "This is not"
```

Here `datetime.date.today()` is the date you want to check if it is alternate Monday or not.
`datetime.date(2020, 6, 1)` This is the date from where you want to start or date of first Monday.